# TextGetTargetedSentiment using AlchemyAPI for input as text, not URL

Tags: sentiment-analysis, alchemyapi

How to get TextGetTargetedSentiment using AlchemyAPI but I want to provide input as text (article) not URL.

This `http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/sentiment/textc.html` provides a way to do this but it takes URL as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the endpoint http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/text/TextGetTargetedSentiment, the only required parameters are apikey and text.  The URL parameter is optional and doesn't need to be included in the query string.  If you are looking at longer blocks of text, it might work best to use one of the [SDKs](http://www.alchemyapi.com/developers/sdks) to help programmatically handle the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your full text in a file. In program read its contents into a string and then call API.

```
String myText= getFileContents("c://myFileToAnalyse.txt");
AlchemyAPI_TargetedSentimentParams sentimentParams = new AlchemyAPI_TargetedSentimentParams();
sentimentParams.setShowSourceText(true);

Document doc = alchemyObj.TextGetTargetedSentiment(myText, "keywords to analyse", sentimentParams);
System.out.print(getStringFromDocument(doc));
```